# Gitlab.com CI/CD ssh permission issue

Tags: bash, ssh, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using CD for deploying my code to a VPS. This VPS is running ubuntu 16.04 and has a user 'deployer'.

Now when I use `ssh deployer@server` I get shell access to the server and then when using `cd /var/www` I get into the `/var/www` directory.

When I do this from the deployment script, defined in .gitlab-ci.yml I get this error `/bin/bash: line 101: cd: /var/www/data/: No such file or directory`. I also did `ls -al` to view the directory structure of `/var` which turned out not to contain the `www` directory. So clearly now I have no permission to the `www` directory.

`- rsync -avz --exclude=.env . deployer@devvers.work:/var/www/data/staging/home
 - ssh deployer@devvers.work
 - cd /var
 - ls -al
 - cd /var/www`

Tthis is the part of the script where it fails. Does anyone know why my user has different permissions when using ssh from the terminal then when using ssh in this script? Coping the files with `rsync` when fine and all the files were copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `cd` and `ls` commands that you are trying are actually executed in the runner's environment (be it the host or a docker container, depending on your setup), not on the machine you ssh into.

I'd suggest you rather execute those commands **with** `ssh`. An example of creating a file and checking that it has been created:

```
ssh deployer@devvers.work "touch /var/www/test_file && ls -al /var/www/"
```

Comment: We're using this solution, but a little bit different.
`ssh "deployer@devvers.work" "cd /var/www/data/staging/;
        other_command;
        other_command;`

Comment: Yep, that's also possible. Just remember that when using `&&` any command is dependent on the success of the previous one which is what you might need in your case, e.g. with `ssh "deployer@devvers.work" "cd /var/www/data/staging/ && first_command && second_command"` the `second_command` would not be run in case the `first_command` fails.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use an ssh executor, [configured through a **`config.toml`**](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md):

```
/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml:

concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  url = "http://your_gitlab/ci"
  token = "xxx..."
  name = "yourGitLabCI"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "deployer"
    host = "devvers.work"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Then you `.gitlab.yml` can simply include

```
job:
script:
    - "ls /var/www"
    - "cd /var/www"
    ...
```

See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33535967/6309).

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the `line 101: cd:` issue on a gitlab-runner that is configured as a shell executor there might actually be a .bash_logout file in the gitlab-runner users home directory that causes the issue together with https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3849