# Git Lab CI/CD for web app running in windows serer(VM) IIS

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I created git lab runners in the server and added yaml CI file in the repo similar to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535967/how-to-use-gitlab-ci-to-deploy-the-project-to-i686-and-x86-64-machine-at-the-sam)

but not working anyone worked on this ?

Comment: What did you succeed to accomplish so far and what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: I succeed creating runner in server, and adding git.ci.yaml in repo and running job with basic commands. Now i want to know how to deploy my code to server after completion of job. @makozaki

Comment: How do you deploy your code so far? Do you have some working script you could use on CI?

Comment: no, i added basic script